# How to send private message to member in on_member_join() discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This is what I have:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    print(f'{member} has joined a server.')
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {member}!")
    await ctx.member.send(f"Welcome to the server!")
```

I need the bot to send a private message containing rules and commands list when he joins.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event `on_member_join()` only accepts member as a valid parameter (see [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join)). Thus what you try to do: `on_member_join(ctx, member)` ,wont work. You need to use this instead: `on_member_join(member)`.

If you used the event as follows:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Private message')
```

You can send messages directly to members who joined the server. Because you get an [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Member) object using this event.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what happened, from one day to the next the bot stopped sending welcome messages to new members. But I was finally able to solve it.
I just had to add these two lines of code. `intents = discord.Intents()` `intents.members = True` [Read](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#try add this 
intents=discord.Intents.all()

#if the above don't work, try with this
#intents = discord.Intents()
#intents.members = True

TOKEN = 'your token'
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

#Events
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Private message')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('My bot is ready')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```