# Discord Bot Joining Message is not working python

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello i try a lot commands to fix it but the bot is doing nothing
Here is my Code. The File are bot.py

```
import discord
import os 
from discord.ext import commands

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

client = MyClient()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} Test!')
    
    
###############

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.system_channel:
        await guild.system_channel.send("Test")

#@client.event
#async def on_member_join(member):
#    await ctx.author.send("Welcome!")

##*@client.event
#async def on_member_join(member):
   
#   await member.create_dm()
   
   
#   await member.send(
#   f'Hallo{member.name}, Willkommen'
#   )
```

Why is it not working i try a lot Commands/models whatever.
I use Notepad++ to programming. Give it a better Programm to programming with Python? Maybe what for Beginners?

Comment: Try PyCharm, Visual Studio Code or something similar. Have you enabled Intents?

Comment: Oke thank you, no but i add now
```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```
but still not working :/

Comment: Have you tried to use a `print` statement? Something like: `print(f"Joined {guild}.")` to see if the event even works?

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525993/how-to-send-private-message-to-member-in-on-member-join-discord-py

Comment: @Dominik its still not working look the Code in the Second Answer :(. And Print i try too :/

Comment: Did you turn on the Intents in the Discord Developer Portal? Do you have more than one `on_member_join`/`on_guild_join`-event? Have you intended the code correctly? (If you create a class you have to do that and then it is mostly `commands.Cog.listener` and `commands.command`. Please edit your code again so we can see how it looks like now.

Comment: My Code is now like this 
`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.member = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


#now you can add events
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.system_channel:
        await guild.system_channel.send("Test")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("welcome!")


# and commands
@bot.command()
async def slap(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author} gave {member} a slap")`

Comment: @Dominik No the Intents on the Developer Portal was off. But it is now on but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use both `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot`, choose one of them.

`commands.Bot` is basically the same as `discord.Client` but with the extra commands feature
-> [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot)

---

```py
# so first remove the client part in your code

# and define the Bot | you can name it 'bot' or 'client' 
# bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
# is the same as 
# client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

# also make sure to enable Intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.member = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


#now you can add events
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.system_channel:
        await guild.system_channel.send("Test")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("welcome!")


# and commands
@bot.command()
async def slap(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author} gave {member} a slap")



# at the very end run your bot
bot.run('BOT TOKEN')
```

Comment: Same Problem when a Friend is Joining the bot do nothing. completly useless. I dont know maybe i am to dumb to programm it. Before i programm with C# but this here is unbelievable for a beginner.

Comment: if you want to use the `on_member_join` event you need to set the `intents.members` to `True`, or what do you mean with `Friend is Joining the bot`? And if the bot doesnt send the 'Test', maybe the guild just dont have a system channel

Comment: Please use the English language as required by this site rules. [How to deal with non-english content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680)

Comment: @Guddi the guys delete the comments because we talk in german xDD never mind. I read it with members. The bot is starting but its still not working.
I turn on the discord developer integrents but still not working :/

Comment: @Guddi nope the bot is starting. I create a Test account in Discord but still no message from the Bot... 

I add again the following programm code:

`@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(f'{client.user.name} Test!')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('welcome !')

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    owner = guild.owner
    await owner.send("hi there!")`
Maybe member is the Problem? Is Member the Role when anyone Joins the Server or i need to Create this Role?

Comment: @Guddi I add now unter guild join and member join : channel.send but this doen't even work .. In Discord Developer Portal is the Bot an Administrator and i turn the Intents bot on. I dont know why it is not working. No Errors nothing. The Bot is completly useless xDD. The Only one message where he gives is in the Terminal "Reality Rekrutieren Test!" and thats all :D

Comment: @Guddi for sure and thank you for your help ;).