# Discord Bot, that gives role to a new members

Tags: python, discord, bots

Bot is simply don`t work :/ The bot doesnt give any errors & roles. I will be grateful for any help

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client =  discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="role_id")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: You have to enable Intents. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525993/how-to-send-private-message-to-member-in-on-member-join-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling intents should solve your problem.

**Firstly**, enable the `Server Members Intent` by following the instructions [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#privileged-intents).

***Next***, implement these intents while initializing your Client object.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

I'm not sure what version of discord.py you're running, but in the most recent one, you add roles with [await Member.add_roles()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id="role_id")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

If you're on an older version of Discord.py, ignore the above snippet.